# How can i extract data from the first column of data frame and insert data in other columns?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a trouble with data frame. I have a csv file with ten columns, but all the data stores in the first column. How can i automatically extract data from the first column and put into other columns? Could you help me, please. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WBYz.png)

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('test_dataset.csv')
df.head(3)
one_column = df.iloc[:,0]
one_column.head(3)
```

This is the link for download file: 
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-aKBLF2YfkyVzhHQUcxcjE2THc)

Comment: Maybe help `df = pd.read_csv('test_dataset.csv', quoting=3)` for correct format

Comment: Yes! It helps me. Thank you a lot! Why do you choose 'quoting=3'? What does it mean? Could you explain me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter `quoting=3` for no quoting in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_dataset.csv', quoting=3)
```

> **quoting** : int or csv.QUOTE_* instance, default 0
>       Control field quoting behavior per csv.QUOTE_* constants. Use one of QUOTE_MINIMAL (0), QUOTE_ALL (1), QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2) or **QUOTE_NONE** (3).